# how to check if a value exists in any array in python dictionary values?

Tags: python

My dictionary looks like:

```
A = {
    (0,0): [(0, 0), (1, 2), (3, 2)],
    (1,1): [(2, 0)],
    (10,1): [(0, 0), (2, 1)]
}
```

Given a new tuple, how do I check if that tuple `(x0, y0)` exist in any of the array in the dictionary values?

I tried to iterate through the list

```
for i, v in iteritems(A):
   if (x0, y0) in v:
       return True
```

Is there a way to make this an one line solution?

Comment: How would you define a tuple existing in an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and put your loops in a generator expression:

```
return any((x0, y0) in v for v in A.itervalues())
```

The `any()` function advances the generator one step at a time, and returns `True` (exiting early) as soon as the `(x0, y0) in v` test returns true. This means only the *minimal* amount of work is done.

Demo:

```
>>> A = {
...     (0,0): [(0, 0), (1, 2), (3, 2)],
...     (1,1): [(2, 0)],
...     (10,1): [(0, 0), (2, 1)]
... }
>>> x0, y0 = 2, 0
>>> any((x0, y0) in v for v in A.itervalues())
True
>>> x0, y0 = 2, 42
>>> any((x0, y0) in v for v in A.itervalues())
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
value = (2, 1)

found = False
for vl in A.values():
    if value in vl:
        found = True
        break

print found
```

Comment: This isn't a one-liner. The OP code simply returns instead of using `break`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, this was answered before OP changed his requirement.

Comment: Right, I missed that they edited their requirements.  You may want to update your post to meet them however.